# Proving that the induced connection on the dual bundle is indeed a connection

Tags: differential-geometry, dual-spaces, connections

I have a hard time proving that the Leibniz property holds of the induced connection on the dual bundle. Let me first outline some definitions.

I will first give the definition of a connection on a vector bundle $E \to M$, after which I'll show the definition of the induced connection on the dual bundle $E^{*} \to M$. I will then show my work and at which part I am stuck.

### **Definitions**

> **Definition 1.** A **connection** on the vector bundle $E \to M$ is a bilinear map $\nabla$
> $$
> \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E),
> $$
> satisfying
> $$
> \nabla_{fX}(s) = f \nabla_X(s), \qquad \nabla_X(fs) = f \nabla_{X}(s) + X(f)s.
> $$
> for all $f \in C^{\infty}(M), X \in \mathfrak{X}(M), s \in \Gamma(E)$.

> **Definition 2.** Let $E^{*} \to M$ be the dual vector bundle of $E \to M$. The **induced connection** on the dual $E^*$ is given by
> $$
> \nabla^{*}_X(\xi)(s) = X(\xi(s)) - \xi(\nabla_X(s)),
> $$
> for all $s \in \Gamma(E), \xi \in \Gamma(E^*)$ and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$.

---

A little note about the notation. Although I am not 100% sure, I suppose the notation $(\xi)(s)$ just means that for $x \in M$, $(\xi)(s)(x) := \xi(x)(s(x))$. In this sense $(\xi) \in \Gamma(E^*)$ must be linear when it comes to the sections $s \in \Gamma(E)$. This means that for $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$, we have (where $x \in M$)
$$
(\xi)(fs)(x) = \xi(x)(f(x) s(x)) = f(x) \xi(x)(s(x))
$$
for all $x \in M$, which can be succinctly written as $\xi(fs) = f \cdot \xi(s)$.

### **Proving the induced connection is a connection**

**Bilinearity + First Condition** (I managed to prove this)

1. Consider $f_1, f_2 \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $X_1, X_2 \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. We write
   \begin{align}
   \nabla_{f_1 X_1 + f_2 X_2}^*(\xi)(s) &= (f_1 X_1 + f_2 X_2)(\xi(s)) - \xi(\nabla_{f_1 X_1 + f_2 X_2}(s)) \\
   &= f_1 X_1(\xi(s)) + f_2 X_2(\xi(s)) - \xi(f_1\nabla_{X_1}(s) + f_2\nabla_{X_2}(s)) \\
   &=  f_1 X_1(\xi(s)) + f_2 X_2(\xi(s)) - f_1 \xi(\nabla_{X_1}(s)) + f_2\xi(\nabla_{X_2}(s)) \\
   &= f_1 \nabla^*_{X_1}(\xi)(s) + f_2 \nabla^*_{X_2}(\xi)(s)
   \end{align}
2. Take $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in \Gamma(E^*)$ (and $s \in \Gamma(E)$). We then write
   \begin{align}
   \nabla^*_X(a_1 \xi_1 + a_2 \xi_2)(s) &= X((a_1 \xi_1 + a_2 \xi_2)(s)) - (a_1 \xi_1 + a_2 \xi_2)(\nabla_X(s)) \\
   &= X(a_1 \xi_1(s) + a_2 \xi_2(s)) - a_1 \xi_1(\nabla_X(s)) - a_2 \xi_2(\nabla_X(s)) \\
   &= a_1 (X(\xi_1(s)) - \xi_1(\nabla_X(s))) + a_2 (X(\xi_2(s)) - \xi_2(\nabla_X(s))) \\
   &= a_1 \nabla^*_X(\xi_1)(s) + a_2 \nabla^*_X(\xi_2)(s)
   \end{align}

**Leibniz Condition** (Here I get stuck)

From here I am a bit confused about multiple things. Namely, we now want to prove that for $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M), \xi \in \Gamma(E^*)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$, we have
$$
\nabla^*_X(f \xi)(s) = f \nabla^*_X(\xi)(s) + X(f)\xi(s).
$$
I hope this is the case at least. From here if we write out from the LHS, we obtain
\begin{align}
\nabla^*_X(f \xi)(s) &= X(f \xi(s)) - (f \xi)(\nabla_X(s)) \\
&= f X(\xi(s)) - (f \xi)(\nabla_X(s))
\end{align}
From here I don't know how to continue. What mistakes am I making. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing out this question, I realised the following: the equality $X(f \xi(s))  = f X(\xi(s))$ is not true. What is true though is, $X(f \xi(s))  = f X(\xi(s)) + \xi(s) X(f)$ due to the product rule. Writing out the Leibniz condition is thus:
\begin{align}
\nabla^*_X(f \xi)(s) &= X(f \xi(s)) - (f \xi)(\nabla_X(s)) \\
&= f X(\xi(s)) +  \xi(s) X(f) - f \xi(\nabla_X(s)) \\
&= f(X(\xi(s)) - \xi(\nabla_X(s))) + \xi(s) X(f) \\
&= f \nabla^*_X(\xi)(s)  + X(f)\xi(s),
\end{align}
which is exactly the property that I wanted to prove.